# Flutter integration test does not fail if an exception occurs

Tags: flutter, testing, exception

I have an integration test which is passing despite an exception occurs during the test. Is it an expected behavior?
I would like any tests to fail if any exception occur, how can I do that?

Here is what I am seeing currently:

```
flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart
```

```
...
I/flutter ( 6014): [27180.076]: {INFO} Fetch data successful 
E/flutter ( 6014): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
...
01:11 +1 ~5: All tests passed!
```

Indeed my test is passing as what I am expecting is happening but after the exception...
I would like any unexpected exception to fail my test.